# Ho to use NSTimer in robovm?

Tags: robovm

I use the NSTimer in robovm , but it not work, I don't know why?
here is my code:

```
mTimer = NSTimer.create(1, new VoidBlock1<NSTimer>() {                  
                    @Override
                    public void invoke(NSTimer a) {
                            onUpdate();
                           System.out.println("onUpdate");
                    }

            }, true);
```

But not happen.

other way:

```
mTimer = NSTimer.create(1, this, Selector.register("onUpdate"), null, true);

@Method(selector = "onUpdate")
    public void onUpdate(){
    System.out.println("onUpdate");
}
```

nothing happen too. and other way is also not work

```
mTimer = NSTimer.create(1, this, Selector.register("onUpdate:"), null, true);

@Callback @BindSelector("onUpdate:")
public void onUpdate(Selector cmd){
    System.out.println("onUpdate");
}
```

it also not work .  please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this, but looking at the [NSTimer.java](https://github.com/robovm/robovm/blob/master/cocoatouch/src/main/java/org/robovm/apple/foundation/NSTimer.java) it seems that you might be creating a timer without starting/firing it.

Perhaps you can try method createScheduled():

```
mTimer = NSTimer.createScheduled(1, new VoidBlock1<NSTimer>() {                  
                @Override
                public void invoke(NSTimer a) {
                        onUpdate();
                       System.out.println("onUpdate");
                }

        }, true);
```

Alternatively if you don't really need it to be an NSTimer I'd recommend using the java.util.Timer. Which works great on Robovm applications.